# Unable to return in before hook in cucumber-js

Tags: javascript, typescript, cucumberjs

Currently I am trying to skip a test in cucumber-js based on tags provided. Looking through their docs it seems pretty straight forward, the following should work.

```
Before({ tags: '@skip' }, async function() {
  return 'skip'
})
```

But when I do this I am getting the following error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
e2e/hooks/hooks.ts(36,1): error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(tags: string, code: TestCaseHookFunction): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ tags: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(options: IDefineTestCaseHookOptions, code: TestCaseHookFunction): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TestCaseHookFunction'.
      Type '() => Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'TestCaseHookFunctionWithoutParameter'.
        Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void>'.
          Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

**Note: I am using typescript**

There seems to be no overloaded method that allows you to return a string. I dug into their source code it does seem to be that there is no overloaded method

```
export declare const Before: ((code: import("./support_code_library_builder/types").TestCaseHookFunction) => void) & ((tags: string, code: import("./support_code_library_builder/types").TestCaseHookFunction) => void) & ((options: import("./support_code_library_builder/types").IDefineTestCaseHookOptions, code: import("./support_code_library_builder/types").TestCaseHookFunction) => void);
```

Am I missing something here? I am fairly new to typescript, so very possible. But it seems as if every method defined for the before function returns void.

Comment: I have been able to get around this problem by reverting cucmber-js to version 6

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution and you are right it's so weird.

use `// @ts-ignore` decorator.

````
import {
    IDefineTestCaseHookOptions, TestCaseHookFunction
} from '@cucumber/cucumber/lib/support_code_library_builder/types';

// @ts-ignore
Before(function (testCase: IDefineTestCaseHookOptions, callback: TestCaseHookFunction): void {
    console.log(testCase);

    // @ts-ignore
    callback();
});

```
````